# Running python jupyter from Windows Ubuntu subsystem

Tags: pip, jupyter, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed `python`, `jupyter`,`pip` on my Windows a while ago, and been running them through the Windows command line. I recently started working on the Windows Ubuntu client, and I want to use all the existing versions of the above without reinstalling them and re-configuring them.
How can I tell the Ubuntu client to do so?

Comment: If the project is in `C:\MyProject` then use`/mnt/c/MyProject` in WSL.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use all the existing versions of the above without reinstalling them and re-configuring them

**No**, You **cannot**. Windows and Ubuntu are different environment, it not a client run on top of Windows as you may *misunderstood*. WSL (windows subsystem for linux) is a "real/authentic" Ubuntu (not yet support GUI).

---

You need to install and config as following:

First, you need to know what version of python on your Windows Environment ( *Windows command line*: *cmd/powershell*)

```
python --version
```

to see python version on your Windows, note that from python 2 to python 3 has a breaking change, so make sure you have the **right version** of python on both environment. Jupyter, Pip and Anaconda depended on your python version.

> How can I tell the Ubuntu client to do so?

Warning: It is not easy for a Windows user to work on Linux environment, search engines are your best friend, there is no .exe to just click and run.

Depending on the version of the Ubuntu distribution you run, the Python install instructions vary.

```
lsb_release -a
```

on your windows subsystem for linux command line to find Ubuntu distribution.

Ubuntu 18.04 come with Python 3.6 by default, Ubuntu 16.04 is not. Making sure you have the same python version which is match with the one on your Windows.

These are some instructions may help you 
[RealPython](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl),[LinuxConfig](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver), [Reddit Bioinformatic](https://www.reddit.com/r/bioinformatics/comments/5ab839/bioinformatics_on_a_windows_computer_how_to_build/), [Xu Lab Wiki](http://www.dxulab.com/wiki/windowssubsystemforlinuxwsl)

Take your time and hope it help!